# Issue with the back button on tool bar

Tags: android

I have created a custom navigation bar. When I click on settings an activity opens and when I click on the back arrow the text remains same. The setting is an activity and rest other are fragments.

This is my Navigation Drawer through which I go to my settings activity:

[image: Navigation Drawer]

This is my settings activity when I go back from this activity, my custom toolbar text doesn't change:

[image: Settings Activity]

You can see here that text doesn't change:

[image: Unchanged text]

Comment: customize your onBackPressed Method or you may ovrride  onOptionsItemSelected

Answer (score 0):

You have to setTitle() in every fragment.You can try below sample code ..

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment{


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View detailsView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_fule,container,false);

    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Settings");  

        return detailsView;

    }


}
```

> MainActivity OnBackPressed

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1)
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        else {
           finish();
        }

    }
```

Comment: That's not an action bar. It is a simple textview that won't change when I go back from settings activity

Comment: ok then set textview text based at place of actionbar set title.